# Changing bases of numeric input (android)

Tags: java, android

I want to take numeric input from an EditText and convert it to a specified base,

i.e. if the input is binary i want to convert it to hex.

I know there are predefined functions for converting decimal to other bases, however I cannot find how to convert when the input is not decimal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code,

```
public void dec(View view) 
{
    try
    {
        EditText decimal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDec);
        EditText hex = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHex);
        EditText bin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBin);
        EditText oct = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editOct);
        int deci = Integer.parseInt(decimal.getText().toString().trim());

        System.out.println ( "Original " + deci );
        System.out.println ( "Hexa : " + Integer.toHexString(deci) );
        System.out.println ( "Deci :" + Integer.toBinaryString(deci));
        System.out.println ( "Oct : " + Integer.toOctalString(deci) );

        hex.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.toHexString(deci)));
        bin.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.toBinaryString(deci)));
        oct.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.toOctalString(deci)));
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println ( "Exception : " + e.toString() );
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it converts integers to all other bases.. but I need binary to another base.

Comment: Then you need to try in two steps, first binary to decimal and then decimal to another base , got it ?